# Usage of Procedure and Map in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am very new to Scheme and I am slowly finding my way around it.

I have some doubts on Procedures and Map which I hope could be answered.

```
(map plus1 (list 1 2 3 4))
```

will basically return me the result:

```
(2 3 4 5)
```

It is fine if the procedure takes in the list as its only parameter. My question is how am I able to use a procedure like such which takes in 2 parameters with Map?

```
(define plus(m list)
    (+ m list))
```

Thanks in advance for help and advice.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this if it were clearer what you want.  Do you want to consume two members of the list for each call, consume one member of two lists, or consume one member of one list with the other parameters being static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (plus m xs)
  (map (lambda (x) (+ m x)) xs))
```

or

```
(define (adder m)
  (lambda (x) (+ m x)))

(define plus (m xs)
  (map (adder m) xs))
```

Which allows you to reuse the `adder` function for other things as well.

Comment: You should not clobber `list`.  Scheme has only a single namespace for functions and other values.

Comment: @Svante: a) It's a local variable, so all I clobber is the local scope of the plus method. b) I just used the names that Darran used. But fine, I changed it.

Comment: Okay, I'll shut up about my pet peeve: a single lower-case l as a parameter looks like a 1.  It's fine, leave it.

Comment: @Jason: Not it's fine, I'm happy to change my variable names in response to comments. I'm nothing if not accommodating.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks! Just so I understand, it is just creating a function to call the Map method and then defining a anonymous function to do the addition?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this?

`(define (plus m n) (+ m n))`

`(map plus (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))`

`; => (list 5 7 9)`

Answer (score 0):

Use two lists.  See what happens:

```
guile> (map (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
(5 7 9)
```